# Add Neo4j to Gremlin Server - how to?

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop

I have downloaded Gremlin Server with an intention of being able to use Gremlin to traverse a Neo4j DB.

Now, speaking of the latter, it has to be somehow added to the Gremlin Server installation, but I have difficulty finding any up-to-date guidance on how to do that. There are a few posts here on SO describing various kinds of problems people run into, but no definitive solution, much less one for the **current** versions of both Tinkerpop and Neo4j.

Would appreciate specific links, tips etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a "TIP" describing Gremlin Server configuration in the TinkerPop reference documentation found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#neo4j-gremlin). Basically, you `-install` Neo4j dependencies:

```
bin/gremlin-server.sh install org.apache.tinkerpop neo4j-gremlin 3.3.4
```

then you edit your Gremlin Server YAML configuration file to connect to your database. Gremlin Server contains a [sample file](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.3.4/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server-neo4j.yaml) to get you started and is found the `/conf` directory of the installation. Of critical note is this entry:

```
graphs: {
  graph: conf/neo4j-empty.properties}
```

It specifies the Neo4j configuration to use and the [sample](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/3.3.4/gremlin-server/conf/neo4j-empty.properties) one that ships with Gremlin Server looks like this:

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph
gremlin.neo4j.directory=/tmp/neo4j
gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.auto_index.nodes.enabled=true
gremlin.neo4j.conf.dbms.auto_index.relationships.enabled=true
```

As you can see, the configuration basically just passes through Neo4j specific configuration to Neo4j itself. Only the first two lines are TinkerPop options. In this case, it sets up Neo4j for embedded mode, meaning Neo4j runs within the Gremlin Server JVM. You can make Gremlin Server part of a Neo4j HA cluster with instructions found in the reference documentation [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_high_availability_configuration).

Note that you asked for "current" versions of both TinkerPop and Neo4j. While these instructions are current for TinkerPop, I'm afraid that the Neo4j version TinkerPop supports is well behind their latest release. It would be nice if someone had time to issue a pull request for that.

Comment: Thank you @stephen mallette. I tried the -install route following an older SO post and ran into some kind of a version mismatch problem.How do we know, it's "neo4j-gremlin 3.3.4"?

Comment: 3.3.4 is the most current release of TinkerPop. you should execute that using Gremlin Server 3.3.4 and thus use neo4j-gremlin 3.3.4

Comment: Sorry, just one more quick question.... I started the server and can see the message "[INFO] GremlinServer$1 - Channel started at port 8182". What I'm trying to do now is connect to the server with Bulbs. Meaning, I need to know Neo4j's address and login details. Could you clarify what those are, given I  followed your instructions above literally? Sure, it's "http://localhost:8182...", but what is the entire path?

Comment: Ah, okay, Bulbs isn't supposed to work with gremlin-server. Again, outdated info based on some SO post.

Comment: I don't think  you should start learning anywhere else besides the official Reference Documentation http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/ and Practical Gremlin http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html - read that stuff first and then when you hit problems search those specific issues out on the internet.